# file in a specific folder gives an error VS2010 Setup Project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, installation

I got a problem with a Setup Project in VS2010.

I have a folder structure and in the folder Bitmaps are all application pictures.

When I build my setup project I get an error that there should be an invalid file in the folder "Bitmaps". But when I check for the file in the specific folder, the file is not there...

I have also opened the vdproj file with an editor the see if the file is referenced in there but that is not the case...

Any ideas??

Comment: you mean excluded items ? select 'show excluded or invisible' and see if you have any problem with those excluded or invisible items. the button usually be on top of solution controller

Comment: No, it doesn't show up there either.

Comment: looks like you have the project shared with tfs or similar and forgot to synchronize those bitmaps (or maybe the committor forgot to check-in) because vs knows that there should be a file with that name (due to references in the code somewhere), but could not find it because it IS missing

Comment: I'm not using TFS, I'm using SubVersion and I am the only Committer so your theorie is off the table... And I know that there hasn't been a file in that folder. there was never such file

Comment: so the file is not supposed to be there? should it be in another location, or? maybe there is a reference in your code pointing to the wrong location of the file

Comment: by the way, you could try to checkout the whole project and see if the problem persists

Comment: The file isn't even in the project and I never had a File called the same is as the file which is refered to

Comment: if the file is not present in subVersion, try to checkout the whole project

Comment: @Leggy7 Let me set this straight... The FILE is not in SUBVERSION NOR THE PROJECT. IT HAS NEVER BEEN THERE..

Comment: in VS building option you could exclude the content folder if I'm not mistaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out the Setup Project multiple times and now it is fixed!